# Adding HTML viewing to Draftail editor on Wagtail

Tags: wagtail

When we were using Hallo.js on Wagtail, I was able to add a button to the editor so you could view the raw HTML of the rich text field.

My Question: Is that still possible in Draftail?

I've looked through the documentation - and successfully wrote my own custom function for Draftail, but it only seems to accept HTML tags for custom buttons.

I see Draftail stores content as JSON instead of HTML, so perhaps that limits this functionality.

Answer (score 5):

There is a (closed) issue on this topic: https://github.com/springload/draftail/issues/156

> Unfortunately there is no such thing possible in this editor, since it doesn’t store its content as HTML. Having such a feature would also go the opposite way to the editor’s general direction – trying to enforce that end users can't alter the content in unforeseen ways.
>
> It would technically be possible to write a toolbar extension that takes the editor’s content, converts it to HTML, allows you to edit that, then inserts whatever was entered back into the editor – but again that completely defeats the purpose of using this editor to start with.
>
> If you need such a feature, you'll probably be better off using an editor like https://www.tinymce.com/ or https://ckeditor.com/.

I would add that any 'complex' html structure is better handled with [StreamFields](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/topics/streamfield.html).

Comment: Thanks, I was the one who finally asked on the repo. I'll leave this here for others that are looking for this information.

Comment: It is a good question! Thanks for bring it up. I'm sure it is helpful to others.